# Obtener valores de un array enviado por jquery en laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

tengo un problema y es que tengo una tabla en la que el usuario va insertando registros que están en la BD, el hace una consulta y cuando los hace se va generando una tabla de estos mismos, una vez que le de clic en guardar esta tabla que el genero se tiene que enviar y registrar en una nueva tabla en la BD, el problema es que estos datos los obtuve por medio de jquery (fue la mejor forma en que pude hacerlo) y después los envió a mi controlador para extraer cada valor por separado y así poder almacenarlos, ya llegue al punto en que puedo obtenerlos en mi controlador, le hago un dd() y en el navegador puedo ver como si llegan correctamente solo que ahora no se como extraer los valores por separado.

Lo siguiente me lo arroja el navegador, esto es cuando ya lo recibí en mi controlador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera es como envió mi información por Jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#enviar').on('click', function() {
     

     var fecha = $("#fecha").val();  
     var operador = $("#idmip").val();
     var captura = $("#captura").val();
     var filas = [];
    $('#table-1 tbody tr').each(function() {
      var codigo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
      var mono = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      var lineitem = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      var pn = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
      var ordenado = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
      var pcspkg = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
      var operation = $(this).find('td').eq(6).text();
      var otiempo = $(this).find('td').eq(7).text();

      var fila = {
        fecha,
        operador,
        captura,
        codigo,
        mono,
        lineitem,
        pn,
        ordenado,
        pcspkg,
        operation,
        otiempo
      };
      filas.push(fila);
    });
   

   $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "{{URL::to('store')}}",
  data: {valores : JSON.stringify(filas)},
  
  success: function(data) { 
    alert("Todo  Bien") //mensaje de envio correcto
     }
   });

  });
});
  

</script>
```

Este es el controlador, basicamente es todo lo que hago

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$request->all();

$array=$request->valores;

    dd(json_decode($array));
}
```

Hice uso de json_decode y ahora me muestra mis valores de otra forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder dar una mejor respuesta, me gustaría ver el código del controlador que recibe la información y el dd que haces.

Comment: Listo ya edite mi pregunta se encuentra al final mi controlador.

Comment: En PHP tienes las funcion json_decode(string). la cual convierte un string que represente un objeto javascript en un objeto php.
puedes ver más infromación en http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Si me funciono convertir la cadena que tengo en mi pregunta que me lanza el navegador, ahora me lo muestra atributo y su contenido, pero ahora como extraigo esos valores para poder almacenarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es convertir en un objeto el arreglo que envías por AJAX de la siguiente manera:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $array = $request->valores;
    $array = json_decode($array);
    $array = (object) $array[0];
    dd($array->fecha);
}
```

Siguiendo el ejemplo ya puedes guardar y manipular cada variable como desees:

```
.....  
$fecha = $array->fecha;
$operador = $array->operador;
.....
```

Comment: Lo intente y me devuelve un valor nulo.

Comment: crees que el error sea mio en como los envio?, porque cada que tengo "una posible solucion" me muestra el siguiente error.

"Trying to get property 'fecha' of non-object"

Comment: Ya vi el error, el problema es que usas `JSON.stringify(filas)`, por lo tanto llega un arreglo dentro de otro, puedes obtenter la fecha de la siguiente manera: `$valores = json_decode($valores);` y la muestras así: `dd($valores[0][0];)` Por favor comentame si te funcionó dime para que edite mi respuesta y ponga un ejemplo de como podrías mandar los datos para evitar este tipo de errores.

Comment: No me da si lo coloco asi me lanza un error que dice que no se puede tratar como una matriz, lo hice con dd($valores[0]); y me devuelve lo mismo solo que evito un arreglo.

Comment: Entonces usa dd($valores[0]["fecha"] para ver si te funciona.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, tendras alguna otra forma de tratar los datos  y no usar JSON.stringify(filas) u otra manera?.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, por favor prueba y dime si te funcionó.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Emmanuel HD tu respuesta me funciono tal y como lo pusiste, en un momento coloco mi respuesta.

Comment: Mi pregunta pudo resolverse tal y como un compañero lo coloco y esto es lo que me devuelve.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZSDJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZSDJ.png)

Comment: Si te ayudé marca la respuesta como correcta, gracias.